# \graphicspath{<filepath>} Yielding Strange Errors

Tags: graphics, pdftex, miktex, texmaker

I am trying to use `\graphicspath` properly, and am having some issues. I am using MikTex 2.9 64-bit on a Lenovo X230.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\author{Jeffrey Wubbenhorst}
\title{math Sandbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{Disposables/idiot.jpg}
\graphicspath{{C:/Users/chire001/Documents/Jeffrey Files/School/Software/LaTeX/Disposables/idiot.jpg/}}
   \caption{A simple caption}
\end{center}
\label{overflow}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

One of the most crytpic errors I am getting is below:

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `Disposables/idiot.jpg' not found.
```

Another error:

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `Disposables/idiot.jpg' not found.See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... ...raphics[scale=0.75]{Disposables/idiot.jpg}
```

I hope this is not a duplicate- at the risk of writing an excelssively long post, here is another piece of code that didn't work. I had some conflicting documentation on the usage of `\graphicspath`, and wanted to try and sort everything out.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\author{Jeffrey Wubbenhorst}
\title{math Sandbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\delta+y \\
Cowbell
\end{equation}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{Disposables/idiot.jpg}

\graphicspath{{C:/}{Users/}{chire001/}{Documents/}{Jeffrey Files/School/}{Software/}{LaTeX/}{Disposables/}{idiot.jpg/}}
\caption{A simple caption}
\end{center}
\label{overflow}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This yielded `! Package pdftex.def Error: File`Disposables/idiot.jpg' not found.See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... ...raphics[scale=0.75]{Disposables/idiot.jpg}'

My apologies for my ignorance.

Best regards,

~Q0rk

Comment: Try to use quotes around the path `"..."`.

Comment: Don't use the `center` environment in `figure`; change `\begin{center}` into `\centering` and remove `\end{center}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are spaces in the path. Package `grffile` adds support for spaces for pdfTeX in PDF mode:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
```